# How to control terminal names in debugging compound?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a workspace with a launch compound that runs 4 debugging sessions. To keep the output separated, these launch configurations use `intergratedTerminal` as the console.

The result is that I now have 4 terminals with the same name:

[image]

Because terminals are not reused, this get's old *real* fast:

[image]

This is obviously not ideal. How can I provide a better name for these consoles?

Answer (score 1):

See [rename terminal sessions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_rename-terminal-sessions).

> **Rename terminal sessions**
>
> Integrated Terminal sessions can now be renamed using the Terminal:
>   Rename (`workbench.action.terminal.rename`) command. The new name will
>   be displayed in the terminal selection drop-down.

Comment: I'd want the terminal to already have the name when it opens. I really don't want to go through every terminal one-by-one after starting my compound to rename the window. Was hoping that'd be obvious ;D

Comment: Given the info in my answer it seems obvious there is no other way.